# Is React always visible in the source code?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a newcomer to React, and I was wondering something. If a site has been built using React, will I always be able to see that in the source code from the developer tools? I installed the ReactJS Super-Powered extension for Chrome, but I don't know how reliable it is.

What should I be looking for if I want to spot React in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not always. You can make them not that visible.

There are many ways to encrypt and uglify the source code.

It will make the source code complicated, ununderstandable, unreadable for humans with only one click. It implied that it could still be decrpted but not that easy.

[A simple Javascript Minifier Compressor Encryptor website](http://www.hightools.net/javascript-encrypter.php)

hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

There is:

1. [React devtools has many features.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en-US)
2. [Show me the react extension is useful.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/show-me-the-react/iaebolhfcmodobkanmaahdhnlplncbnd?hl=en-US)
3. And react uses specific keys to keep track of the dom and keep it quick which could possibly be recognized in the dom.

Answer (score 2):

Delete all the .map files /js and /css folder from your generated build.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't set the following option, your react source code (not minimized) will be visible. You need to turn off the GENERATE_SOURCEMAP flag.

in package.json

"scripts": { ... "build": "GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false react-scripts build", ... }